# Twig for loop over an array

Tags: symfony, twig

can someone tell me why isn't this working ? `i` isn't recognized as a (1, 2 or 3) but like an `i`:

```
{% set test = '' %}
  {% for i in range(0,2) %}
    {% set test = test ~ ' ' ~ myArray.i  %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Here's my array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "test "
  1 => "test "
  2 => "test "
]
```

Comment: What's the structure of `myArray`? It seems like its keys do not contain indexes from 0 to 2.

Comment: what is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 'i'th element of an array you need to use brackets like `myArray[i]`.

Also as an improvement you can simply use `for i in 0..2` in twig instead of range (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).

Comment: Yes thank you but i have a question, in my loop if  i do a: 
{% set test =  test|replace({i:myArray[i]})  %}

i -> is a number in the string... I figured out that it's not replaced but if a write a {% set test =  test|replace({2:myArray[i]})  %} for example to test it works..

Comment: Try: ``{(i): myArray[i]}``.

Comment: thank you so much i haven't found that anywhere in the doc :(